# Fetching python class name while using abstract classes with `abc` library

Tags: python, abc

I want to extract the python class name while using abstract classes with `abc` library. I unfortunately instead receive the class name `ABCMeta`.

```py
import abc

class A(abc.ABC)
    pass

class B(A)
    pass

print(A.__class__.__name__)  # output: 'ABCMeta'
print(B.__class__.__name__)  # output: 'ABCMeta'
print(str(A))  # output: "<class '__main__.A'>"
print(str(B))  # output: "<class '__main__.B'>"
```

I expect that I should receive the output as below

```py
print(A.__class__.__name__)  # output: 'A'
print(B.__class__.__name__)  # output: 'B'
```

The `str(A)` and `str(B)` seems to print the class name so I assume the class name can be extracted from somewhere. But nonetheless, I am not interested to use `str` to parse and get the class name.

Comment: Consider: what is the type of the object bound to the names `A` and `B`?

Comment: use `__name__` instead of `.__class__.__name__`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that a metaclass is the *type of a class*, while a class is the type of its instances.

If we have `a = A()`, `a` is of type `A`, and `A` is of type `abc.ABCMeta`. Therefore, you should naturally expect that `A.__class__` and `B.__class__` both return `abc.ABCMeta`, since they are instances of it!

What you want is the names of `A` and `B` themselves, which you can get with `A.__name__` and `B.__name__` respectively.

Comment: What if I want instantiate a object of type "A", if I use A.__class__(), not work. (I need use this form)

Comment: You can use A.__mro__[0] to get the actual class object.

Answer (score 4):

Use just the `__name__` property

```
print(A.__name__)
#A
```

`A` in itself is a class, if you use `A.__class__` you are getting it’s metaclass therefore it’s metaclass’ name.